# What is Dyon's Memory Model?

Tags: memory-management, rust, dyon

The [Dyon Tutorial](http://www.piston.rs/dyon-tutorial/) says it uses "lifetimes" rather than garbage collection or manual memory management. But how then does that lifetime model differ from Ownership in Rust?

> Dyon has a limited memory model because of the lack of a garbage collector. The language is designed to work around this limitation. - *The Dyon Programming Language Tutorial*

How exactly is this model limited? Is there an example of memory managing code that Dyon could not run because of this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

The linked [Dyon book](http://www.piston.rs/dyon-tutorial/lifetimes.html#Lifetimes%20are%20about%20references) contains an explanation to just that:

> #### Lifetimes are about references
>
> A lifetime is about the references stored inside a variable. All references outlive variables they are stored in. Variables can not store references to themselves, because it can not outlive itself.
>
> In order to put a reference inside a variable, the lifetime checker must know that the reference outlives the variable.
>
> Because of the lifetime checker, all memory in Dyon is an acyclic graph.

Therefore, the main limitation is that references *cannot make any cycles*. That is, it is not possible to represent circular node lists or having a child object keep a reference to its parent.

These limitations also apply to Rust, with the exception that Rust also provides workarounds. Reference-counted types (`Rc` and `Arc`), in combination with weak references (see [`std::rc::Weak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Weak.html)), can create circular references. Cycles can also be made behind `unsafe` constructs, namely raw pointers.

See also (Rust specific, but most principles apply):

- [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Comment: It reads to me as if the Dyon rules are more limiting than Rust's rules, since in Rust you *can* create self-referential structs in safe code, but Dyon claims to prevent that (that is, the reference must *strictly outlive* the variable it is stored in, while in Rust it only need live *at least as long as* the variable).